# Rails plugin. How to insert data into the DB during plugin task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, plugins

I need to run seeds for my rails plugin and put them into the task.
Following code insert empty records to the table

```
namespace :my_plugin do
  desc "Run seed for plugin"
  task :seed => :environment do
    settings = [
        [ 'Detail', 'detail' ],
        [ 'Approximate', 'approximate' ]
    ]
    settings.each do |name, anonym|
      Setting.create!( name: name, alias: anonym )
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I've got the solution for the problem

```
settings.each do |name, anonym|
  Setting.find_or_create_by(alias: anonym) do |setting|
    setting.name = name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared settings as an array and then you are trying to iterate over it like you do for key,value store.

You can do following to make it work.

```
namespace :my_plugin do
  desc "Run seed for plugin"
  task :seed => :environment do
    settings = {'Detail' => 'detail',
                'Approximate' => 'approximate'}
    ]
    settings.each do |name, anonym|
      Setting.create!( name: name, alias: anonym )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Iterator each works fine in both cases. I checked it just insert the line
`puts "#{name} #{anonym}"`  <br/>
And it display:
Detail detail
Approximate approximate

Comment: Do you have any validations in Setting model ? May be some validation is failing or something ?

Comment: I don't have any validations in this model